# Eclipse : Copy Paste over existing files

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

I'm kind of ashamed to ask this question, but cannot find how to copy-paste multiple files/folders structure from one project to another and overwrite all existing nodes.

The objective is following :

Suppose I have project `A` with following sturcture
src/

```
   folder1/
          file1
          file2
   folder2/
          file3
          file4
```

and project `B` with following structure

```
   folder1/
          file1
          file5
   folder2/
          file6
          file4
```

How can I copy `folder1` and `folder2` from project `A` to project `B` and overwrite `file1` and `file4` elements ?

Plain copy-paste says

```
"The element XXX exists in the selected destination. You can either skip the
conflicting element, skip all conflicting elements, or cancel the whole operation."
```

Platform : eclipse-juno

Comment: Do it outside of eclipse with a cp/copy or with nautilus/explorer and then refresh inside Eclipse.

Comment: Thats how I did so far

Answer (score 0):

Use **Navigator** view there you will be able to override existing files/folders

Window Menu Bar -> Show view -> Navigator